# Getting ocassional 503 errors on azure website

Tags: iis, azure

I'm getting occasional 503 errors on our site.  It usually happens after not visiting the site for a while.  The whole page might return 503 or just some resources like css or js files.

It seems to go away after you've surfed the site for a bit and hit all of our servers.

Elmah doesn't show any errors.

I've gone into the logs on each of our servers (three medium web roles on azure) and I can't find any problems.

Our deployment has been up since December without a code change, we've been having this problem for about a week.

One thing to note is that when this happens the site doesn't shut down.  I would think that would happen if IIS was crashing and restarting (even with three servers).

Does anyone know how to diagnose or fix this problem?

Comment: Hi Nate. Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @skhro87 no :(.  It doesn't happen anymore though.  We did stop using Umbraco, so maybe that was related.

Comment: I found that my problem was that an uncaught exception brought it in an unstable state. I fixed the exception and now it seems stable again. However not a really nice solution :/ Thanks for your feedback though!

Answer (score 3):

While this *could* be code related, I'll assume you've already explored this route as much as possible via logs (and since you haven't deployed new code). Having said that:

Do your issues align with the Compute service degradation events shown in the [Azure Dashboard](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/) over the past several days? Look at Historical View and you'll see a few issues around Compute. Depending on your data center, maybe this is related?

[image]

Comment: We're north central.  Good idea though.